# iOS - remove uilabel or uiimageview from only one table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to remove specific views from my `UITableViewCell` based on some condition, for example:

```
if (!model.isThumbnail) {
  // remove thumbnail UIImageView
  [cell.thumbnailView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

but this will remove `UIImageView` from all following cells as well..

Is it possible to remove it only per one specific cell (without creating several different cells)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `UITableViewCell`s are reused somewhat automatically, removing individual views from cells would be problematic.  Say that you're using two cell layouts, one, layout1, removes view1, the other, layout2, removes view2.  Now if a cell is initially configured for layout1, view1 is removed.  The next time it gets reused, it gets reused for layout2, so view2 is removed and view1 was removed the last time, so now it's missing both views.

As implied in CEAFDC's answer, a better approach might be to hide (and subsequently show) those views that aren't necessary.

IMO, a better approach would be to use completely different cell layouts (you can even use the same sub-class, just different use different prototypes in the storyboard) and create whichever layout you need at the time.

Comment: I ended up with this approach after all

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a tag to the specific cell...
Can you show how you create the cell? or tell why you need to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem, but I think this would solve:

```
if (!model.isThumbnail) {
    cell.tumbnailView.hidden = YES;
} else {
    cell.tumbnailView.hidden = NO;
}
```

or

```
cell.tumbnailView.hidden = !model.isThumbnail;
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
if (!model.isThumbnail) {
    // remove thumbnail UIImageView
    [cell.thumbnailView removeFromSuperview];
} else {
    if there is no thumbnailView on cell {
        // create thumbnailView and add to cell
    }
}
```

But anyway this isn't good solution.